# Can not Open Routes on Different outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I have to  in my app.component.ts , the name of one of them is name='popup':

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>
               <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public construnctor(){ }

  ngOnInit(){ }

}
```

and my route definition is:

```
    export const myappRoute: Routes =[
      {
       path: '',
       component : DataEntryComponent
      },
      {
         path: 'templateModal',
         component: TemplateModalComponent,
         outlet: 'popup'
      }
    ];

export const TemplateRoute: ModuleWithProvider = RouterModule.forChild(myappRoute);
```

when i try open the 'templateModal' route with code below:

```
<button type='submit' [routerLink]="['/' , {outlets: {popup : 'templateModal'}}]" replaceUrl="true"> open </button>
```

I take an error that said Cannot match any routes with Url segment templateModal . 
I'm on Angular 5
and this is StackBlitz for try on this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2eaje

Answer (score 1):

> use non-empty paths for your top level routes if auxilary(i.e. named)
>   routes exist in a lazy loaded module.

```
<button type='submit' [routerLink]="['home', {outlets:{popup:['templateModal']}}]"> open </button>`
```

and replace **templateUrl** with **template** because you added template view not the URL

like,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>
               <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>`
})
```

here's is the updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trrwau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: templateIUrl replaced with template and edit the routerLink like that you said, but it's not work the first time i try to navigate to 'templatModal' route take : Error error : [object Object]  and the secound time said can not match any route to the route that i'm on it.

Comment: check this demo... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trrwau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: if you check the question i use forChild in my router module but you put forRoot in your sample , if i can't change it because of lazy module it makes problems ?

Comment: check this i put it on a lazy module .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2eaje

Comment: I have updated my answer and Stackblitz also.. have a look into this.